# How do call function from another class

Tags: ios, swift

How could a call a function from another class? Ill found some solutions for Objective C, but nothing especially for Swift.

I want to reload a Table in another View, so first try do to it this way:

```
var dashboard:DashboardViewController!
dashboard.tableView.reloadData()
```

But that is not working, so created a custom func to test

```
var dashboard:DashboardViewController!
dashboard.refreshTableView()
```

But always get the **error**:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I thought that every class functions in Swift are public?

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning anything to dashboard. You can't call a function on it if it doesn't exist.